# Add Delay Between GET Requests on Button Click

Tags: jquery, get

I'm using JQuery to trigger a series of GET requests to an API upon the click of a button. However, I need to add a short delay between the execution of some commands.

```
$('#VideoPlay1921').click(function() {
    var videoname = 'Video.mp4';
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=AudioBusOn&Value=M&Input=" + videoname);
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=AudioChannelMatrixApplyPreset&Value=Video&Input=" + videoname);
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=Restart&Input=" + videoname);
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=SetVolume&Value=75&Input=" + videoname);
    // delay needed
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=Play&Input=" + videoname);
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=ActiveInput&Input=" + videoname);

$('#L3In2019').click(function() {
    var topline = 'BOTHWELL MIDDLE SCHOOL';
    var bottomline = 'MARQUETTE';
    var singleline = '';
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=SetText&Input=L3&SelectedName=L3 Single In.Text&Value=" + singleline);
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=SetText&Input=L3&SelectedName=L3 Single Out.Text&Value=" + singleline);
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=SetText&Input=L3&SelectedName=L3 Top In.Text&Value=" + topline);
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=SetText&Input=L3&SelectedName=L3 Top Out.Text&Value=" + topline);
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=SetText&Input=L3&SelectedName=L3 Bottom In.Text&Value=" + bottomline);
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=SetText&Input=L3&SelectedName=L3 Bottom Out.Text&Value=" + bottomline);
    // delay needed
    $.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=TitleBeginAnimation&Value=TransitionIn&Input=L3");
});
```

Adding delay(500) or sleep(500) didn't seem to help. For example:

```
$.get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=SetText&Input=L3&SelectedName=L3 Bottom In.Text&Value=" + bottomline).delay(500);

$.delay(500).get("http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=TitleBeginAnimation&Value=TransitionIn&Input=L3");
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` to execute something after a delay.

Comment: Thanks, that's come up a few times. I'm going to rework my code to better handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
$('#VideoPlay1921').click(function() {
  var videoname = 'Video.mp4';
  var urls = [
    "http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=AudioBusOn&Value=M&Input=",
    "http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=AudioChannelMatrixApplyPreset&Value=Video&Input=",
    "http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=Restart&Input=",
    "http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=SetVolume&Value=75&Input=",
    "http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=SetVolume&Value=75&Input=",
    "http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=Play&Input=",
    "http://10.6.18.228:8088/API/?Function=ActiveInput&Input="
  ];
  $.each(url, function(i, u) {
    $.get(u + videoname, function() {
      if (i + 1 == 5) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("I waited");
        }, 500)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is not the best practice in my mind. the best practice would be to make a single call to the API and have the API perform the needed tasks. Or, if you want to perform multiple, yet maybe different tasks, send the file name and the tasks to the API. If they need to be done via API calls, have your Server Side script perform them via cURL or some other method. LEaving it all in the browser leaves a lot to chance.

You did not indicate why you needed the delay? If one takes longer to load than others,  maybe you need to perform the next GET request in the `success` of the first.

Comment: Thanks, this may help. I'm going to try restructuring my code and use functions in conjunction with "setTimeout."